# Type Error : Float is not callable

Tags: python

the code simply gives the number of months for payment of loan.

```
import sys

loanAmt = input("enter the amount of loan you want : ")
r = input("enter the rate of interest : ")
numOfPayments = input("enter number of payments : ")
month = loanAmt ( r * (1+numOfPayments) / ((1+r) * (numOfPayments-1)))

print(month)
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: 'float object is not callable '
```

Comment: I don't get that error from this code, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` because `input()` returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

`loanAmt` is a float, and you are trying to call it:

```
month = loanAmt ( ... )
```

Perhaps you wanted to *multiply* that value by the outcome of the parenthesised expression? If so, you are missing a `*`:

```
month = loanAmt * ( ... )
```

The full line then should be:

```
month = loanAmt * (r * (1 + numOfPayments) / ((1 + r) * (numOfPayments - 1)))
```

Comment: I don't get it, surely `loanAmt` is a string?

Comment: @cdarke: in Python 2 `input()` evaluates the input as a Python expression. Entering `4.2` will get you a float. The exception clearly shows it is a float.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed Python 3 because of the `print()` function.